# How does Ornstein-Uhlenbeck arise in quantum mechanics?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator, [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_operator) is a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ (with respect to Gaussian measure).

I've heard it comes up in QM, and I'm wondering how? Does it represent some observable and does it have a conjugate variable?